# The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context, ajax url and response data member

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Here is a function called by my controller:

```
    public ActionResult ExecuteRule(string rawSql, List<PdsMatchRuleParam> parameters)
    {
        var da = new DataAccess();
        var ruleSql = ruleRawSql.Replace(@"{KEY}", "@pkey");
        var dbParameters = new List<DataAccess.DbParameter>();

        dbParameters.Add(new DataAccess.DbParameter("pkey", DbType.AnsiString, 4000,
            parameters[4].DefaultValue));

        var dt = da.Select(ruleSql, dbParameters.ToArray());

        // Required to eliminate "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'" exception
        var db = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,
            Formatting.None,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });

        var result = new JsonResult()
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        };
        result.Data = db;

        return result;
    }
```

The above ds.Select call properly returns data.  After the above code executes, when I analyze the network traffic in my browser, gives me this info:

```
General:
Remote Address:[::1]:41678
Request URL:http://localhost:41678/Match.mvc/RuleResultsGrid? _=1436385801737
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

When I check the value of Request in the immediate window, this is what I get:

```
The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context
```

Here is some of my javascript code:

```
function execRule() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ExecuteRule",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ruleSql : PageState.SqlEditor.RuleSql.getValue(),
            parameters: PageState.RuleParameters
        }),
    }).done(function(obj) {
        PageState.RuleResultsGrid = response.queryResultsContainer;
        bindRuleResults();
    });
}
```

What am I missing?  Is it something I have not set up properly in my JavaScript?  Does the 'Request' property need to have a value, because when another function is called in the same controller, 'Request' also does not exist, but it properly returns data for the Kendo grid?  Here is the network log of executing the other method in the same controller that populates the data grid:

```
General:
Remote Address:[::1]:41678
Request URL:http://localhost:41678/Match.mvc/ExecuteRuleSet
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Please note that my application supports authentication, but I have it completely turned off during development, so I should not be getting the "401 Unauthorized" error because of a permissions problem.  It seems that for some reason ASP.NET MVC is not generating a response page.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I've found one problem--in the execRule function I had url improperly set to the name of the rule result grid `url: "RuleResultsGrid"`, instead of the name of the controller action.

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
  at Object.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:1)
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:55)
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
  at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:954:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:41678/Scripts/Match/eiq.match.config.js:617:45)
  at fire (http://localhost:41678/Scripts/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js:1037:30)
  at Object.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:41678/Scripts/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js:1148:7)
  at done (http://localhost:41678/Scripts/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js:8084:14)
  at XMLHttpRequest.send.callback (http://localhost:41678/Scripts/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js:8608:8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the problem--here is the fixed execRule():

```
function execRule() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ExecuteRule",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ruleSql : PageState.SqlEditor.RuleSql.getValue(),
            parameters: PageState.RuleParameters
        }),
        success: function (matchedList) {
            PageState.RuleResult = matchedList;

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: matchedList
            });
            Grids.RuleResultsGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
            updateButtonStates();
        }
    });
}
```